# TableView Cell Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, uitableview, null, option-type, tablecell

I have been using the same protocols and functions throughout all projects. But this one is giving me hard times with fatal error.

This is my Nibloadable

```
 protocol NibLoadable: class {
    static var nib: UINib { get }
}

extension NibLoadable {
    static var nib: UINib {
        return UINib(nibName: String(describing: self), bundle: Bundle(for: self))
    }
}
```

This is my Reusable

```
    protocol Reusable: class {
    static var reuseIdentifier: String { get }
}

extension Reusable {
    static var reuseIdentifier: String {
        return String(describing: Self.self)
    }
}
```

in VideoListTableViewCell

```
static let identifier = String(describing: VideoListTableViewCell.self)
extension VideoListTableViewCell: Reusable, NibLoadable { }
```

inside my VideoViewController

```
class VideoViewController: UIViewController, VideoModule.View  {
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var presenter: VideoModule.Presenter!
var videos: [VideoModel]?

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        presenter.fetchVideos()
        configureTableView()
    }
func configureTableView() {
        tableView.register(VideoListTableViewCell.self)
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

extension VideoViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return configureTableViewCell(indexPath: indexPath)
    }
    
    func configureTableViewCell(indexPath: IndexPath) -> VideoListTableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: VideoListTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! VideoListTableViewCell
        let videoData = (videos?[indexPath.row])!
        cell.configure(model: videoData)
        return cell
    }
```

So inside configureTableView function at .register it throws fatal error. I have tried adding an identifier to create my cell and register tableView but it also did not solve this problem.

at the .register line my tableView is tableView UITableView?    nil none with the error explanation.

And finally my UITableView Extension

```
extension UITableView {
  
    func register<T: UITableViewCell>(_: T.Type) where T: Reusable, T: NibLoadable {
        register(T.nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: T.reuseIdentifier)
    }
    
    func dequeueReusableCell<T: UITableViewCell>(forIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> T where T: Reusable {
        guard let cell = dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: T.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? T else {
            fatalError("Could not dequeue cell with identifier \(T.reuseIdentifier)")
        }
        return cell
    }
```

I have tried using VIPER so this is my VideoContract

```
 protocol VideoModuleViewProtocol: AnyObject {
  var presenter: VideoModule.Presenter! { get set }
  
}

protocol VideoModuleInteractorProtocol: AnyObject {
  var presenter: VideoModule.Presenter? { get set }
  
  func fetchVideos()
}

protocol VideoModulePresenterProtocol: AnyObject {
  var view: VideoModule.View? { get set }
  var interactor: VideoModule.Interactor! { get set }
  var router: VideoModule.Router! { get set }

    func fetchVideos()
    func didFetch(videos: [VideoModel])
}

protocol VideoModuleRouterProtocol: AnyObject {
  
}

struct VideoModule {
  typealias View = VideoModuleViewProtocol
  typealias Interactor = VideoModuleInteractorProtocol
  typealias Presenter = VideoModulePresenterProtocol
  typealias Router = VideoModuleRouterProtocol
}
```

I have created storyboard file as VideoListTableViewCell.xib and created both tableviewcell files at the same time. Everything is connected to the correct places too.

How can I overcome this meaningless problem?

Comment: So if you do `print(tableView)` before `tableView.register(...)`, it crashes, right? So, it crashes because `tableView` is `nil` and it shouldn't. If that's the case, don't care for now about the registering, it's not the issue. So how is created the `VideoViewController` instance?

Comment: Updated my code for you to see clearer.

Comment: I don't see where you initialize the `VideoViewController` instance. If you wrote at some time `VideoViewController()`, that's the initialization, and it's an error. But I can't confirm it. Or are you using a `segue`?

Comment: I didn't use a segue. Where should I init VC in Viper?

Comment: I'm not a user of VIPER, I understand its principles, but never used it. You have at least write somewhere `VideoViewController()` or something like that, no? Your `viewDidLoad()` didn't get called out of nowhere, no? It's not about where (that's for VIPER to decide), it's about how. If you did write `VideoViewController()`, then, that's the issue. But I'm looking for a confirmation of that...

Comment: Perhaps you need to set the presenter object before using it in your viewDidLoad override. Either at initialization time or by injecting it in the view controller after it has been initialized.